# scrapy deny certain length of words

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to implement a deny rule where i don't want to crawl a certain length of words.

Example:

https://example.com/a/comments

https://example.com/z/blog

https://example.com/t/public

this is my deny rule:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('[\/a-zA-Z\/]{0,2}')),
                  callback="parse_page",
                  follow=True)]
```

i want to deny anything that 1-2 letter short between * **/** *.

with this command it basically just ends the crawl instantly with no errors.

Thank you

***UPDATE***

If there is 1 or 2 letters between the slashes (For example the letter **a**: "https://example/**a**/comments")  i don't want to crawl it.

I know i can deny **comments** (this is easy) but there also "https://example.com/a/all"... using same letter **a** but different path after it..

Comment: `deny=('\/[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\/')` might work

Comment: i have tried that too...it still ends my crawler instantly with no errors

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? you dont want to crawl any URL having 1-2 letters after `https://example.com/` ... if it has more than 2, then crawl it?

Comment: yes thats correct..i will update the question

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your pattern:

- Your slashes are inside `[]`; `[\/a-zA-Z\/]` matches a letter or a forward slash.
- `{0,2}` will match 0 occurrences of a pattern, as well as 1 or 2, making your pattern match the `//` in `https://`.
  You want `{1,2}` instead.

This pattern should work as intended: `r'/[a-zA-Z]{1,2}/'` (using a raw string for simplicity).

Also (not a problem here), `(a)` is the same as `a`, if you want a one-tuple, you should use `(a,)`.